# Ubuntu Installer freezes

Tags: system-installation

Im trying to install ubuntu to my lenovo thinkpad p52 (intel i7 and nvidia quad p520), and when i select my usb from the devices to boot from option, it loads the ubuntu iso and i selected *install ubuntu* from the options, it briefly loads the ubuntu splash screen. After that it loads the installer and after around 30 seconds it just freezes. I've tried retrying but to no avail. Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Ps. I have disabled secure boot

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset` install Ubuntu , then install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: How do i set "nomodeset"?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/167850

Comment: Wait, lol i thought i disabled secure boot, turns out i didnt. Hopefully that solves it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Secure Boot shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I just gave up and used xubuntu which worked first try